# Создание теней android

Tags: android, android-material

При помощи elevation тени для android 4.2 не отображаются на устройсве, но на 5.0 они видны.
Делал так

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/open_poup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="open poup"
        android:background="@drawable/my_shadow"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        />
```

drawable ресурс my_shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#42000000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**Как можно добиться эффекта тени для android 4.2 ?**

Answer (score 2):

Некоторые советуют использовать такой метод:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

Когда же сам с таким сталкивался, то данный метод не подходил по некоторым причинам, поэтому сделал костыль в виде замены `Button` на `CardView` с поведением кнопки.

Comment: как при применении  android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame" задавать цвет фона, drawable и тд ??? или

Comment: @Vitaliy, можете свой перерисовать. К примеру, взять `dialog_full_holo_light.9.png`, закинуть к себе в `drawable`, изменить цвет/фон и подставить вместо `"@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"`. Ищите png в `SDK` папке.

Comment: а лучше так сделать или все-таки  CardView ?

Comment: @Vitaliy, вряд ли можно ответить однозначно. Лучший вариант конечно когда доделают `ViewCompat.setElevation`. Можете посмотреть на `CardView`, подойдет ли Вам, но поведение тоже различается на preLollipop  и Lollipop+.